# Set grey background around main area

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to get the look of this app using material ui:

[image: Seeking this look]

Currently, my app looks like this:

[image: Current look of my app]

There are a few things I need to do. Put some kind of box around the Keyword Processor text, put a box around the stuff below it, set background colour of central area boxes to white and have the background area of the rest to grey.

Any ideas how to modify my code below to do this?

````
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
       
        </ThemeProvider>

        <div>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Container>
              {/* <Box bgcolor="primary.main"> */}
              <Grid container spacing={2}>
                {/* <Grid xs={12}>
              <AppBar />
              <br />
            </Grid> */}

                <Grid item xs={12}>
                  <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
                    Keyword Processor
                  </Typography>
                  {/* <br /> */}
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6}></Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                  <Box textAlign="right">
                    <Button
                      color="primary"
                      // mt={5}
                      onClick={this.inputToOutput}
                      //**********************
                    >
                      A-Z
                    </Button>
                  </Box>
                  {/* <Typography align="right">A-Z Frequency</Typography>{' '} */}
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                  <TextField
                    label="Input Keywords"
                    fullWidth
                    multiline
                    rows={10}
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    onChange={this.handleInputText}
                    defaultValue={defaultInputText}
                  />

                  <br />
                  <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    mt={5}
                    onClick={this.inputToOutput}
                    //**********************
                  >
                    Parse
                  </Button>
                  <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    color="secondary"
                    mt={5}
                    // onClick={this.parseInput}
                  >
                    Clear
                  </Button>

                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <Checkboxes
                    handleDedupe={this.handleDedupe}
                    handleRemoveNumbers={this.handleRemoveNumbers}
                    handleConvertToLowercase={this.handleConvertToLowercase}
                    handleOneWordPerLine={this.handleOneWordPerLine}
                    handleAddCommas={this.handleAddCommas}
                    handleAddCommasSpace={this.handleAddCommasSpace}
                  />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                  <TextField
                    label="Output Keywords"
                    fullWidth
                    multiline
                    rows={30}
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    value={this.state.outputText}
                  />
                  <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    mt={5}
                    onClick={this.clearOutput}
                  >
                    Copy
                  </Button>
                  <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    color="secondary"
                    mt={5}
                    onClick={this.clearOutput}
                  >
                    Clear
                  </Button>
                </Grid>
                <Grid>
                  <br />
                  <br />
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
              {/* </Box> */}
            </Container>
          </ThemeProvider>
        </div>
      </>```
````

Comment: have you tried giving background color to `Container`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that all, here is what you can do instead. I believe the `theme` you added to `ThemeProvider` is custom, the edit the theme file `pallete` object to `background` colors i.e `paper` and `default`, the `default` color is what you need.

Here is mine:

```js
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

// Main Material UI theme
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    background: {
      paper: '#fff',
      default: '#fafafa',
    },
  },
});

export default theme;
```

Change '#fafafa' to the color you want.

If you didn't create a custom theme, just copy mine then import it in your `ThemeProvider`, it will change the background of your body in all your html pages.

Comment: I cannot get that to work, although my understand is not very good. I'm trying to paste my Theme.js file in comments but it just shows inline and so is a mess.

Comment: No no, you should import it in the `App.js`  and add it to the root `ThemeProvider` component, usually it is in `App.js` but some put root ThemeProvider in `index.js` I don't know for your case where it is, but the point is to import that file theme.js and add it to the root ThemeProvider that you configured when you were adding Material UI.

Comment: I have import theme and {ThemeProvider} in App.js. I put your code in my Theme.js file. Using that, it didn't work. So I am just thinking, is {ThemeProvider} a hook, because I am using a class component? Wonder if that is anything to do with it.

Comment: Can I have a look at your `App.js` and how you used `ThemeProvider` there and remember to remove the `Container` that covered the whole background of the page maybe it is a reason you don't see the changes.

Comment: I got a solution now thanks. Found I had to import and use <CssBaseline />

Comment: Yes, I would have notice that If I saw your App.j, good news you got it working, happy hacking!